# How to place form inside another form in aspx

Tags: asp.net, html, forms

I wants to add a form element inside another form .

I am using Master page in my page. So the Master page contains a form with "runat=server".

But now I am using a plugin which requires a form element in the child page. When I tried to add another form it is showing in the firebug and also the plugin is not working. As I am using more then 1 plugin in my project I can't mention all the things in the master page form element.

Is there any process to use inherited Form element in asp.net. I think in HTML5 it is supporting all multiple form element in a page.

Please suggest.

Comment: When you put form on master page and when it renders in the browser you content page also contains form. What is the point to have form on content page.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I am using two different plugin which need form with different settings. Example: Jquery File Upload, Validation Plugin . Both requires it own form with different settings. I think we can solve this using inherited form

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms do not support multiple forms.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? or we can't use multiple plugin in an form :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have two forms on your page in .net webforms you'll need to have the second form in an iFrame.